# Binding to column(cell) value

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-wpf

I am trying to customize a column inside a DevExpress `GridControl`. I basically want two rows in each cell in the column. One with some random text and another one containing the property `Max` defined in my `ObservableCollection` `Stocks`, which is set as the ItemsSource. Without using the `GridColumn.CellTemplate` the cell receives has the correct `Max` property value. But when the `Grid.CellTemplate` is introduced I am unnable to have the `Max` property value printed out. I'm assuming the Binding is incorrect but cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
     <dxg:GridControl  EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Stocks}" 
                     SelectionMode="None" AllowLiveDataShaping="True"     >

           <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
             <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="MaxColumn" Binding="{Binding Max, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="60" Width="60" AllowResizing="True" 
                FixedWidth="true" Header="Max" ReadOnly="True">
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Max is..." ></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding Max, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
              </dxg:GridColumn>
           </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

    </dxg:GridControl>
```

The first picture is without the `CellTemplate`, the second one is with the `CellTemplate`.

[image: Without the CellTemplate]

[image: With the CellTemplate]

Appreciate all help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this issue is the incorrect `Binding Path`. Please note that the CellTemplate content uses the GridCellData object as DataContext. The Binding Path should look different based on what `ViewModel` contains the required command:

The source is a row's ViewModel:
**XAML:**

```
Command="{Binding RowData.Row.Max}"
```

The source is bound to the DXGrid control as DataContext:
**XAML:**

```
Command="{Binding View.DataContext.Max}"
```